# How can I set up a virtual private network on Windows?

Tags: networking, vpn

I don't like the standard VPN server on Windows for some reason, and I'm searching for the best client/server application in order to create a [virtual private network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network).

I don't care if the application has its own technology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi2/) :

> LogMeIn Hamachi is a hosted VPN
>   service that securely connects devices
>   and networks, extending LAN-like
>   network connectivity to mobile users,
>   distributed teams and business
>   applications. You can easily create
>   secure virtual networks on demand,
>   across public and private networks.
>
> 100% free for non-commercial use with
>   up to 16 clients. Perfect for gamers
>   and home networking.

Comment: hamahchi is NOT a real VPN solution it Will NOT connect the rest of his network like a real VPN can do. IE  access to the local network of the remote system above and beyoned the connected server

Comment: On the other hand, if it applies it's the simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

Try [OpenVPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVPN). It works with *all* OS's.

Comment: We're using OpenVPN with great success.  The OpenVPNGui works well for our Windows clients, and it is quite a bit less "system intrusive" than traditional IPSEC clients (e.g. Cisco)

Answer (score 3):

Another vote for OpenVPN; especially [OpenVPN Portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ovpnp/) as it allows you to distribute a VPN client that does not require installation for Windows users - just unzip and go.

Other attractive features:

- Per-User routing/DHCP configurations
  (for example, push routes to some users and
  not others)
- RSA Certificate authentication
- Toggle client-to-client communications
- Firewall friendly